# Finding several injected but unknown - matching upper and lower tags in text with regex, then output files named after each section

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to export sections out of a text file that were previously injected with the following formatting.

**InFile.txt**

```
::DATABIN::
::LINExOFxTEXT
::MORExTEXT
::UNKNOWNxNUMBERxOFxLINES
::UNKNOWNxTAGxNAMES
::DATABIN::
```

This works perfectly fine for a single section for which the name is known e.x. **`::DATABIN::`**

```
$file = Get-Content 'infile.txt'
$result = [regex]::Match($file,'\:\:DATABIN\:\:(.*?)\:\:DATABIN\:\:').Groups[1].Value.Replace(' ',"`n").Replace('::','') | Set-Content 'outfile.txt'
```

Powershell grabs all the text between the two identical **`::DATABIN::`** tags, removes the double colons and the tags themselves, then adds linebreaks where spaces are (at the end of each line) and outputs the data to a file.

**OutFile.txt**

```
LINExOFxTEXT
MORExTEXT
UNKNOWNxNUMBERxOFxLINES
UNKNOWNxTAGxNAMES
```

**My Goal:**

I will be adding multiple datasets to the infile, I dont know what the section names will be  yet and I am trying to think of a way to find all **`::RANDOMTAG::`** sections pragmatically to spit out anything it finds between matching tags contained inside.

I cannot seem to wrap my head around the best way to do this with powershell.. Obviously I can find and replace the value but using regex to find the tags puts me outside of my comfort zone and I am a bit stumped..

Ive seen `([regex]::escape($myString)` but I dont know how to add it to `[regex]::Match` or if that is the best direction.

Comment: It seems like task for backreference. Something like `::([A-Z]+?)::(.*?)::$1::`. But I'm not sure on support of those in powershell, so sorry if out of place here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to gather anything between two tags of the form: `::tag:: <whatever> ::tag::`, then you can use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) (that's a good link to learn the basics about it). Here is an example using two approaches -- one which hardcodes the tag-name and one which just matches based on matching dynamic tags.

[`::DATABIN::(.+?)::DATABIN::`](https://regex101.com/r/HhF0Vl/1)

[image]

[`::([^:]+)::(.+?)::\1::`](https://regex101.com/r/naRCtK/1)

[image]

Two things to note:

- Make sure you have the option 'dot-matches-newline' selected.
- The second approach using the backreference requires a capturing group so that first tag can be referenced. In other words, you'll want to used the second capturing group to get the data you want between the tags.

---

**Update**: I suppose in Powershell it would be this (copy-pasting from your question), but I have zero knowledge of Powershell myself, so take this with a grain of salt.

```
$result = [regex]::Match($file,'\:\:([^\:])\:\:\1\:\:').Groups[2].Value
         .Replace(' ',"`n").Replace('::','') | Set-Content 'outfile.txt'
```

Comment: Is there a way to add the dynamic section name to a var using the regex solution? If not I may be able to use another route to name the output file. Im already thinking of other ways as im typing this may be back to delete this soon ;P

Comment: Hey @PlayLORD-SysOp sorry I don't follow -- could you please give an example of what you mean? Do you mean how to do that in Powershell, or something else?

Comment: I made this with the regex answer I got here.  but it only supports a single file. the problem is even if there is a solution (probably a loop through the file) I am trying to squeeze it all on one line and there probably isnt a way to maintain that format.. On top of all of that its being pushed through a cmd script..

Anyway its just a toy that was fun to get all the esc char's and single line if then quirks worked out, and the self delete etc.. 

TheBAG: 
https://github.com/illsk1lls/BAG

Answer (score 2):

You can use backrefereces for you task:

```
[regex]::Match($file,'::([A-Z]+?)::(.*?)::\1::').Groups[2].Value.Replace(' ',"`n").Replace('::','') | Set-Content 'outfile.txt'
```

Here any word of upper letters between `::` will be captured as delimiter and matched later by `\1`.

Also, notice I've used `.Groups[2]` instead, since I've introduced new group matching tag.

For multiple blocks in the same file you can use `.Matches()` instead, and you'll get an array of all matching block (possibly with different tags)

Comment: I cant get this to work. The colons need to be escaped for it to work, like my example. But because there are extra "magical" regex chars there, im not sure what is or isnt safe to escape. I tried testing it a few ways with no luck. Is there any way to use a variable for the section name? Then i could make it work..

Comment: @PlayLORD-SysOp, strange, I tested and it worked without escaping of colons.